# Linux system monitoring

Tags: monitoring

I'm looking for tools to monitor the linux system. I would like to know what are the best/ most used monitoring tools for linux, preferably command-line or with the possibility to be used from the command line too.

I am aware that are a lot of individual tools for monitoring a specific resource, but I want to know if there is a "all in one" system monitoring tool that can be used.

Comment: do you want to use monitoring tools locally on the system, or did you consider remote monitoring tools as well?

Comment: Nagios or Munin - take your pick: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/monitoring.html

Comment: how is that different your previous question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/575396/linux-watchdog-handler ?

Comment: @Rinzwind Taking Nagios, it doesn't do anything other than monitoring. That question asks for something which can take action as well (such as restarting processes).

Comment: Ah ok. Is assumed this to be a collection of the other question.

Comment: @aFoP i want to use monitoring tools locally.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what you pretend to do with it, if is just want to read some info from your system from time to time, there are lots of commands like top (cpu process usage), ps -le (process status), lm-sensors give you a bit more info. Then you have other ones that give you info constantly on your desktop like gkrellm or conky. googling you will find a lot more options..

Answer (score 0):

To monitor your Linux system's performance locally I would suggest you to read http://www.tecmint.com/command-line-tools-to-monitor-linux-performance/
and http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html